# Solve for x of spring-mass system using method of Laplace transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I was told to apply the method of Laplace transforms to solve for x.

the displacement $x:=x(t)$ of a spring-mass satisfies the IVP:
$$\ddot{x}+4\pi^2x=\sum_{k=1}^3 2\piδ(t-k)$$ for all $t>0$,
and $$x(0)=7$$ $$\dot x(0)=0$$
The summation on the right represents 3 impulsive forces applied to the spring-mass system externally at time $t=1,2,3$.

I tried expanding the summation on the RHS, giving $$\ddot{x}+4\pi^2x=6\piδ(t-2)$$ (which was differnet from Cesareo suggested).  Then, applying Laplace transformation in both sides resulting in $$L(x)=\frac{6\pi e^{-2s}+7s}{s^2+4\pi^2}$$
I am not sure if i get the Laplace transformation right. May I know how can I proceed to solve for $x$? Shall I just go for the inverse Laplace transforms? Thank you so much.

Comment: To me the transform gives $s^2 X(s)+4 \pi ^2 X(s)-s x(0)-\frac{2 \pi  e^{-3 s}}{s}-\frac{2 \pi  e^{-2 s}}{s}-\frac{2 \pi  e^{-s}}{s}-x'(0)=0$

Comment: @Cesareo do you mean the summation on the right should not be simplified to $6\pi{δ(t-2)}$ before proceeding to the transformation?